# More tables or More records performance wise

Tags: mysql, innodb, schema, normalization

i am into a scenario that upon looking at the our project database contains Identical tables with the schema described below:

```
  id
  url
  region_1
  region_2
  region_3
  region_4
  date_created
```

My colleague creates a table in each category a url appears so the database looks like this

```
angular
   id
   url
   region_1
   region_2
   region_3
   region_4
   date_created

 react
   id
   url
   region_1
   region_2
   region_3
   region_4
   date_created

 asp
```

**Same schema and it goes on and on.....**

my proposed schema will look like this

```
sites
   id
   url
   region_1
   region_2
   region_3
   region_4
   date_created
   tech_category
```

This would satisfy the ORMs (Dapper/EF) on the application level to be more maintainable and will just use a single table. What is the right approach? Is it more favorable to create a single table to hold the data or is multiple tables with smaller sets of data?

Comment: your question is actually diiffcult to answer, your table(s) doesn't look normalized to me, but the main issue is that you want to use different technologies on the same database amd tbales, that iks possible, but also you can't react to changes that are neccessary, because the technology changes. More technologies you involve more  the smallest common denominator that you used that every thing fits, could hinder you.future progress or force you to to put much more source code that it fits.

Comment: my problem is when the technology changes from time to time and if new technology is detected, it will again create a specific table for that. Not like i have a single table and ill store the technology to the category column. It would be easier and is a lot more maintanable

Comment: each table represents which site uses that specific technology. that would mean 100 or even thousands of tables so that's the main problem

Comment: yes i understand that, but you would only because of the costs reduce it to only 1 server technology and 2 or 3 clients and you also have to maintain 100 or more technologys, so that little sql wouldn't hurt. As i said if all use the same data lets them access the same tables. so if tech 1 needs to access data from tech2 perfekt lets put all toghether, but then you don't need to differentiate between technologies, **so**your theoretical concept has no solution, there isn't a clear pro and contra where one side wins
'

Comment: It's not like that. A single application will consume those table. The technology is just for the naming. In my point of view it would just be equal to a category.

Answer (score 2):

Both of these schema anti-patterns have been repeatedly refuted:

- Do not have multiple 'identical' tables.
- Do not spread an array across columns.

So have one table with lots of rows:

```
    sites
       id
       url
       region
       value
       date_created
       tech_category
```

Use suitable composite indexes for efficiency.  (We need to see your `SELECTs` to advise further.)

Use "pivoting" to make the 4 region columns.  (Or >4 when you increase the number of regions.)

As for "performance"...  If you don't have a billion rows, performance is probably not a problem.  When the table gets that big, we can discuss "summary tables".

Comment: I deleted my post on stack. This is what im thinking of. Since we can spread the regions when doing the select. I just need the inputs to suggest the restructuring of the schema. Right now we are storing 330M records.

Comment: @EduCielo - 330M is getting toward "big"; there may be performance issues.  To discuss this, we need to see the queries and other aspects of the big picture.  (Start a new Question if you want to tackle performance issues.)

Comment: i would surely do. that is my concern specially using the data for reporting purposes